# php mail() - "From" header interrupts sending

Tags: php, email

I got a code like this:

```
$headers = '';
//$headers .= 'Reply-To: "site\'s name" <newsletter@example.com>'."\r\n";
//$headers .= 'From: "site\'s name" <newsletter@example.com>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'."\r\n";

mail($_POST['email'], stripslashes($result['title']), $message, $headers);
```

As long as those two lines are commented out, it sends emails correctly. Otherwise - it just doesn't. Without giving any error or even notice. It worked (uncommented code) until yesterday and now it stopped. Any ideas, why would it happen? I cannot use Swift or anything like that, because it's not my project.

**Edit:** incorrect quoting, but that wasn't the problem.
**Edit:** damn, it was just server admins, they blocked all mails with headers from non-existing accounts. I just had to create such mailbox, and i started working back again...

Comment: Taken From PHP.net "If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some Unix mail transfer agents (most notably » qmail) replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822."

Answer (score 2):

You have an error on `site's name` try with correct quoting

```
$headers .= 'Reply-To: "site\'s name" <newsletter@example.com>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: "site\'s name" <newsletter@example.com>'."\r\n";
```

Comment: It's not that :( The real site's name has no quotes, it's only here where I messed it up.

Comment: can you paste an example

Answer (score 0):

You can add header as the code below. Remove unwanted single quotes and double quotes. Just simple write as below.

```
$headers = "From: site name <newsletter@example.com> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: site\'s name <newsletter@example.com> \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
```